# How to write $x^{p-1}-1$ as $(p-1)x^{p-2}\cdot g(x)+(p-1)\cdot r(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

How to write $x^{p-1}-1$ as $(p-1)x^{p-2}\cdot g(x)+(p-1)\cdot r(x)$? How to find the appropriate polynomials $g(x),r(x)$

$\deg r(x)$ needs to be less than $p-2$

For context I am trying to show that if the caracteristic of the field over which those polynomials lie divides $p-1$ than $x^p-x$ has a multiple root.

I tried to work with $g(x)=x$ but it seems like it's not going to work this way...

Comment: If the characteristic divides $p-1$, then *all* roots of $x^{p-1}-1$ are multiple. After all, the formal derivative is $(p-1)x^{p-2}=0$

Comment: So, ok the derivative is zero, what does that imply?

Comment: @JohnCataldo That already implies there are multiple roots (in fact, just one...)

Comment: If $\alpha$ is any root, then $x^{p-1}-1=(x-\alpha)\cdot g(x)$ and the derivative on the right hand side is $g(x)+(x-\alpha)g'(x)$, so that $g(\alpha)=0$

Comment: I don't know how much help it will be but: 
$$x^{p-1}-1=(x-1)(x^{p-2}+x^{p-3}+\cdots+x+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Over a field of characteristic $\ell$ where $\ell\mid(p-1)$, then
$$x^p-x=x(x^{(p-1)/\ell}-1)^\ell$$
and so certainly $1$ is zero with multiplicity at least $\ell$.